# Asynchronously run different animations in manim

Tags: python, animation, manim

I'm trying run essentially two animations (ref. following code):

```
class RelTrain(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        train = Rectangle(height=1, width=4)
        train2 = Rectangle(height=2, width=2)
        train.move_to(np.array([-10,0,0]))
        train2.move_to(np.array([0,0,0]))
        self.add(train, train2)
        self.play(
            train.move_to, np.array([10,0,0]),
            train2.move_to, np.array([15,0,0]),
            run_time=18,
            rate_func=linear,
        )
        self.wait()
```

Essentially two rectangles are moving, but I do not want them to begin movement simultaneously. I want `train` to start moving, and after 2 seconds (`train` would still be moving at this point since `run_time=18`), I want `train2` to pop up on the screen and begin its motion. I'm not sure how this is done and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

After playing for a while, I've figured how to do this **with [ManimCE](https://www.manim.community/)** (v0.3.0). This is not very well documented yet, but essentially you can use [mobject updaters](https://docs.manim.community/en/v0.3.0/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.add_updater). I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this (it seems to me that is too much verbose and low level), but it works:

#### Code

```py
import numpy as np
from manim import *

class DeplayedTrains(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        # create both trains
        trains = (
            Rectangle(height=1, width=4),
            Rectangle(height=2, width=2),
        )
        
        # indicate start and end points
        start_points_X, end_points_X = ((-5, 0), (5, 5))
        # compute movement distances for both trains
        distances = (
            (end_points_X[0] - start_points_X[0]),
            (end_points_X[1] - start_points_X[1]),
        )
        
        # place trains at start points and add to the scene
        for train, start_point in zip(trains, start_points_X):
            train.move_to(np.array([start_point, 0, 0]))
            self.add(train)
        
        # deifine durations of movements for both trains, get FPS from config
        durations, fps = ((5, 3), config["frame_rate"])
        
        # create updaters
        updaters = (
            # add to the current position in X the difference for each frame, 
            # given the distance and duration defined
            lambda mobj, dt: mobj.set_x(mobj.get_x() + (distances[0] / fps / durations[0])),
            lambda mobj, dt: mobj.set_x(mobj.get_x() + (distances[1] / fps / durations[1])),
        )
        
        # add updaters to trains objects, movement begins
        trains[0].add_updater(updaters[0])
        # wait 2 seconds
        self.wait(2)
        
        # start the movement of the second train and wait 3 seconds
        trains[1].add_updater(updaters[1])
        self.wait(3)
        
        # remove the updaters
        trains[0].clear_updaters()  # you can also call trains[0].remove_updater(updaters[0])
        trains[1].clear_updaters()
```

#### [Output](https://youtu.be/QprGQVrXvx8)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to making animations start at different times while still partially temporally overlapping, take a look at `LaggedStart` and similar things:

https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.composition.LaggedStart.html#manim.animation.composition.LaggedStart

https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.animation.composition.html

Unfortunately they are not documented, but it took me a while to realize they even existed.